# PHP Multiply Sum

Tags: php

I have a small script, I have it adding up all of the number in a MYSQL column and echoing the result. I am trying to take the sum or echoed number and multiply it by 100. I can't seem to get it to echo the multiplication.

Here is the code i am using. Any help would be great, Thanks in advance.

```
//connect to db

$q = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(oil_production) as sum FROM wp_wct3 WHERE oil_production > 0") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

echo $row['sum']; echo " BOM" 

echo $total = ($result['sum'] * 100);

?>
```

Comment: You need a semicolon after echo " BOM";
$result should be renamed to $row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
echo $row['sum']; echo " BOM" ;
echo "Monthly Income based on $100 Oil = $";
echo "<span style=\"color:#00ff00\">";
echo $total = ($row['sum'] * 100);
echo "</span>";

?>
```

---

EDIT -

ONCE You're referring the array of results as `rows[]` and once as `results[]`... this it the error...

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. anybody know how I can make the echoed response Green. Here is the code I am using now.<?php

echo "Monthly Income based on $100 Oil = $"; echo $total = ($row['sum'] * 100);
?>

Answer (score 1):

```
$result= $row['sum'] * 100;
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its should be. You wrote `$result` instead of `$row`

```
echo $total = ($row['sum'] * 100);
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. anybody know how I can make the echoed response Green. Here is the code I am using now.<?php

echo "Monthly Income based on $100 Oil = $"; echo $total = ($row['sum'] * 100);
?>

Comment: Dont put code in here update your post if you have new question

Answer (score 0):

echo in your case will out the result of the assignment, which is "true" if assigned.

Assign it to $total, then echo $total:

```
$total = $result['sum'] * 100; echo $total;
```

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: No, the result of the assignment is the value that got assigned.

Comment: Ha! totally missed the variable names. Thanks.